# Formatting Namenode in ubuntu

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to install hadoop on ubuntu 12.04.Following is the error i get on typing:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

> ERROR namenode.NameNode: java.io.IOException: Cannot remove current directory: /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name/current

On typing `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh namenode` does not start

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I followed Michael noll for installing hadoop on a single node cluster and I executed **bin/hadoop namenode -format** and it threw the exception that you mentioned.

Trying ***sudo bin/hadoop namenode -format*** solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Stop All Running Service : Stop-all.sh
>
> 2.Edit /usr/local/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml

```
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
<value>/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name/data</value> 
<final>true</final> 
</property> 
<property> 
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name</value> 
<final>true</final>
```

If data and name directory all ready there than make new directory

```
> mkdir -p /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name(Here give new name)

> mkdir -p /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data(Here give new name)
```

Than change group to hadoop

> sudo chown -R
>   hduser(hadoop_user):hadoop(hadoop_group)/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name/
>
> sudo chown -R
>   hduser(hadoop_user):hadoop(hadoop_group)/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data/
>
> 3.This Name and Data directory Name also change in hdfs-site.xml files
>
> 4.Than Format the name node and start all service.

Also check file permission...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have proper directory permissions for the user you are using to issue these commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **sudo** before the command. Also, as @Tarik said, check for your directory permissions

Answer (score 0):

use below link for your hadoop cluster configuration.

http://cs.smith.edu/classwiki/index.php/CSC352_Hadoop_Cluster_Howto